# Xamarin.Forms ListView duplicate items on Android

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, listviewitem

When I run the app on Android, only the first few items in the ListView are displayed correctly, every item after that is a duplicate of one of the first shown items on the list. This is only an UI and not a logic problem, because when I select an item from the list, the SelectedItem is set to the correct item from the list.

Also, the color is correct only on the first card, the colors on the other cards are not the correct colors for the corresponding item.

**The app runs perfectly on UWP, this issue is only on Android.** My guess is that it has something to do with the ListView Caching Strategy (RetainElement, RecycleElement or RecycleElementAndDataTemplate). I have tried making custom ListView controls and setting the different Caching Strategies, but no luck so far.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance

[image: Android vs UWP]

*This is the ListView in XAML:*

```
<ListView 
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
ItemsSource="{Binding Cards}"
HasUnevenRows="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="5, 2.5"
                             BackgroundColor="{Binding CardColor.Pale}">
                    <BoxView HeightRequest="10" BackgroundColor="{Binding CardColor.Bright}"/>
                    <StackLayout Padding="10, 2.5, 10, 10">
                        <Label Text="Date" FontSize="10"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

*Card.cs*

```
public class Card : MvxNotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _id;
    private string _title;
    private string _text;
    private CardColor _cardColor;

    public int Id { get => _id; set => SetProperty(ref _id, value); }
    public string Title { get => _title; set => SetProperty(ref _title, value); }
    public string Text { get => _text; set => SetProperty(ref _text, value); }
    public CardColor CardColor { get => _cardColor; set => SetProperty(ref _cardColor, value); }

    public Card(int id, string title, string text, CardColor cardColor)
    {
        Id = id;
        Title = title;
        Text = text;
        CardColor = cardColor;
    }
}
```

*CardColor.cs*

```
public class CardColor
{
    public Color Bright { get; set; }
    public Color Pale { get; set; }

    public CardColor(Color bright, Color pale)
    {
        Bright = bright;
        Pale = pale;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what MvxNotifyPropertyChanged does (I know it is some MVVM framework), but it is probably causing the problem as without it I know it works. You can try simple INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I just tried it, but the issue persists. BTW the MvxNotifyPropertyChanged is part of MVVM Cross, and does the same job as INotifyPropertyChanged, with the easement to use SetProperty() method instead of manually calling the NotifyPropertyChanged().

Comment: I ran into the same issue, though only reported on Android 6 so far, newer versions seemed OK.  Setting the ListView's caching strategy to RecycleElement fixed the problem in the emulator at least.